# How to change outer margin in memoir page template semiisopage?

Tags: margins, memoir

Yet another question regarding margins in LaTeX. I am using a thesis template which uses memoir with a pre-defined page template:

```
\documentclass[twosided,onecolumn,openright,11pt]{memoir}

\newcommand\thesispapersize{
\setstocksize{240mm}{170mm}
\settrimmedsize{240mm}{170mm}{*}
}

\newcommand\thesisgeometry{\semiisopage[9]}
```

However I would like to have a smaller outer margin. One option I tried and though it should work is:

```
\setpagetm{20mm}{20mm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
```

I get an Class memoir Error:

> \spinemargin (97pt) and/or \textwidth (369pt) and/or foremargin (148pt) are too large for
> \paperwidth by 612.295pt

The weird thing is that the number 612.295pt doesn't change when I change the parameters in setpagetm.

I would greatly appreciate any help on how to fix this and center my semiisopage.

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example such that we can see exactly what you are doing. Note that `\setpagetm{20mm}{20mm}{*}` does not make much sense as it is a special version of `\settrimmedsize` and it sets the paper size to 20mm by 20mm. So it might be better if you explained exactly what it is you are trying to do

Comment: Sorry that it wasn't clear, but all I want to do is to be able to change the (outer) margins while still using \semiisopage[9].

Comment: But the example you provide does not show how those macros you provide are used. This is why we alwas insist getting full examples that others can copy and test as is. Tip: you can use the `kantlipsum` package and its `\kant` command to get filler text.

Comment: Also it is not obvious from your question whether you still want to have the same text width aka move the text block. Or if the text width should just go down when you increase the outer margin.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things here

1. Use

   ```
    \setstocksize{240mm}{170mm}
    \settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
   ```
2. here is what `\semiisopage[9]` actually does

   1. set the spine and upper margin to `\textwidth/9`
   2. defines the text block as

      ```
      \setlrmarginsandblock{\spinemargin}{*}{2}
      \setulmarginsandblock{\uppermargin}{*}{2}
      ```

      This means that the text block is such that the outer margin is twice the size of the spine margin. Thus you can just copy these two lines and change the first `2` to something larger

All in all this would solve your problem

```
\setstocksize{240mm}{170mm}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\semiisopage[9]
\setlrmarginsandblock{\spinemargin}{*}{2.2}
\setulmarginsandblock{\uppermargin}{*}{2}
\checkandfixthelayout % very important
```

Additionally: there is no option called `twosided` its called `twoside`